# Pyramid - make user object available in every request produces maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, pyramid

I followed this instruction from http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/auth/user_object.html and all I got is: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

It seems like it goes into infinite recursive call between `get_user()` function and `groupfinder()`.

Comment: Some relevant code and a fragment of a (supposedly very long) traceback would be useful...

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to post your code.  I do exactly the same method you mention and do not have that issue, so it must be the way you're implementing.